# if no detecta que tenga un valor a 9999

Tags: javascript

Ahora mismo estoy recreando una pelea de un famoso videojuego en la que , si el programa detecta que el jugador tiene 9999 de vida, los hechizos de recuperación no hacen efecto. Sin embargo, si tiene menos, le da +1% cada segundo durante X.

Aquí tengo el fragmento del código:

```
rec.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    
    let recu = setInterval(function(){

        if(pj_hp == 9999){
            document.querySelector('.healed').innerHTML='MERMA';
            setTimeout(function(){document.querySelector('.healed').innerHTML=""},50);
        } 
        else {
            let san = parseInt(9999/1.99);
            pj_hp = pj_hp+san;
            document.querySelector('.healed').innerHTML=san;
            setTimeout(function(){document.querySelector('.healed').innerHTML=""},50);

            if(pj_hp > 9999){
                pj_hp = 9999
            }
        }
    },100);
    let cls = setInterval(function(){
        clearInterval(recu); clearInterval(cls)
    }, 10000);
    document.querySelector('.au-content').innerHTML = '';
    setTimeout(function(){selectTurn(arma_hp, pj_hp, arma_vel, pj_vel, res)},3000);
});
```

Lo primero que el primer if, no detecta bien si el pj está a 9999, ya que, en los dos primeros turnos, lo va a estar. Y le cura, a parte de no un 1%, casi un 60%. Ya me contaréis el por qué del asunto.

No se qué parte del código tengo mal y llevo ayer atascado con ello y yo juraría que está bien. Eso si, no funciona como yo quiero que funcione.

Respecto a la operación de `let san`, ahora mismo está en 9999/1.5, pero anteriormente la puse a 9999/1.99 y nada tampoco, ni 1% ni nada.

¿Qué tengo mal planteado?

---

---

**[EDIT]**

Vale, gracias a @Trauma he conseguido solucionar el problema de la vida y el "MERMA". Ahora viene el por qué no se aplica el 1%...Yo juraría que la operación es correcta...Pero a saber.

Comment: Si quieres el 1%, ¿por qué no multiplicas 9999 * 0,01?

Comment: `9999/1.99` es casi lo mismo que 10000/2, unos 5000 aproximadamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sin entrar en detalles de dónde deseas mostrar el resultado, una forma de calcular los valores, de acuerdo a lo que planteas en tu pregunta sería la siguiente:

```js
let max_life = 999
let pj_hp = 950;
console.log(`Vida: ${pj_hp}/${max_life}`);
let recu = setInterval(() => {
  if(pj_hp < max_life) {
    pj_hp = (pj_hp * 1.01).toFixed(2); // 1% de aumento
    console.log('Curando...');
  }
  if(pj_hp > max_life) {
    pj_hp = 999
    clearInterval(recu);
  }
  console.log(`Vida: ${pj_hp}/${max_life}`);
}, 2000);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Lo interesante es saber en qué momento se lanza el proceso de cura automática, para ello basta activarlo cuando se cumplan ciertos parámetros dentro de la dinámica del juego, como por ejemplo si la vida es menor que cierto valor.

Supongamos que tenemos el siguiente código, en el cual se inicia una serie de juegos, hasta determinado número, en cada juego un jugador resta vida del otro.

Cuando la vida de cualquiera de los jugadores baja del límite establecido por `init_recu` se incia el proceso de cura del mismo.

Se almacena el valor de los identificadores de recuperación en cada jugador, para poder finalizarlos con `clearInterval` en el momento adecuado.

Esto es sólo un modelo básico de la implementación que creo que buscas.

```js
let max_life = 999;
let init_recu = 800;

let player1 = {
  nombre: 'Mauricio',
  vida: max_life,
  recu: null
}

let player2 = {
  nombre: 'AQMR',
  vida: max_life,
  recu: null
}

let mensajes = [
  'Para que aprendas!',
  'Toma!',
  'No me vencerás!',
  'Ganaré!',
  'Kame Hame Ha!'
];

let juegos = 0;

function jugar(p1, p2) {
  let fight = setInterval(() => {
    let point = Math.round(Math.random());
    if(point) {
      let mensaje = mensajes[Math.floor(Math.random() * mensajes.length)];
      p2.vida = p2.vida - Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
      console.log(`${p1.nombre} golpea a ${p2.nombre} diciendo: ${mensaje} y le deja ${p2.vida} de vida.`);
      if(p2.vida < init_recu) {
        if(!p2.recu) {
          recuperar(p2);
        }
      }
    } else {
      let mensaje = mensajes[Math.floor(Math.random() * mensajes.length)];
      p1.vida = p1.vida - Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
      console.log(`${p2.nombre} golpea a ${p1.nombre} diciendo: ${mensaje}, y le deja ${p1.vida} de vida.`);
      if(p1.vida < init_recu) {
        if(!p1.recu) {
          recuperar(p1);
        }
      } 
    }
    juegos++;
    console.log(`Juegos: ${juegos}`);
    if(juegos > 15) {
      clearInterval(fight);
      console.log('Final:');
      console.log('------------------');
      console.log(`${p1.nombre}: ${p1.vida}/${max_life}`);
      console.log(`${p2.nombre}: ${p2.vida}/${max_life}`);
      console.log('------------------');
    }
  }, 3000);
}

function recuperar(player) {
    let recu = setInterval(() => {
      if(player.vida < max_life) {
        player.vida = (player.vida * 1.05).toFixed(2); // 1% de aumento
        if(player.vida < max_life) {
          console.log(`Curando a ${player.nombre}... ${player.vida}/${max_life}`);
        }
      }
      if(player.vida > max_life) {
        player.vida = 999;
        console.log(`${player.nombre}: ${player.vida}/${max_life}`);
        clearInterval(player.recu);
        player.recu = null;
      }
    }, 2000);
    player.recu = recu;
}

console.log('Inciando el juego');
jugar(player1, player2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Espero que esto te ayude a solucionar el problema.